# Can I transfer Metal Gear Solid 3: Snake Eater Subsistence saves to PlayStation and unlock trophies?

Tags: emulation, ps2, metal-gear-solid-3-snake-eater, pcsx2

I played and completed MGS 3: Snake Eater Subsistence on the PCSX2 emulator and have a post-credits save file.

If I transferred it to my Playstation, would it automatically unlock any trophies I earned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, the trophies [would not unlock](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/938583-littlebigplanet/answers/10093-will-saved-games-from-gamefaqs-unlock-trophies).**

You can only unlock trophies by actually earning them, so loading a save will [not retroactively grant you trophies](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/playstation-nation-1000002/do-game-saves-unlock-trophies-27489145/).